# Android HLS playback: Passing url parameters as headers in Mediaplayer.setDataSource() does not work properly

Tags: android, http, parameters, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have an HLS m3u8 playlist hosted on a server:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/crypt.key?e=6889c9ad1087852"
#EXT-X-VERSION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10,
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment1_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b
#EXTINF:10,
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment2_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b
#EXTINF:10,
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment3_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b
#EXTINF:10,
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment4_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b
#EXTINF:10,
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment5_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b
#EXTINF:10,
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment6_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

but there are extra url parameters needed to retrieve the playlist, i.e. the calls will look like this:

```
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment1_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b&param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Setting the headers as key-value pairs on the [setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri, Map headers)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29) does not work, at least the way I am trying it. Here is how I create the headers from the original url parameters:

```
String paramString =playlistUrl.substring( playlistUrl.indexOf("?") + 1);

String paramsSplit[] = paramString.split("&");
HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

for(int i= 0;i<paramsSplit.length;i++)
{
     String key = paramsSplit[i].substring(0, playlistUrl.indexOf("="));
     String value = paramsSplit[i].substring(playlistUrl.indexOf("=")+1, playlistUrl.length() );
     headers.put(key, value);//e.g headers.put("param1", "value1");
 }
```

Thus I end up with a Map with my parameters in it (i.e. Map'<'param, value'>'), but adding these headers does not work.

If i go through the playlist m3u8 itself and amend every single url call with the extra parameters on the end myself, so the playlist is as follows:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/crypt.key?e=6889c9ad1087852b&param1=value1&param2=value2"
#EXT-X-VERSION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10,
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment1_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b&param1=value1&param2=value2
#EXTINF:10,
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment2_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b&param1=value1&param2=value2
#EXTINF:10,
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment3_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b&param1=value1&param2=value2
#EXTINF:10,
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment4_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b&param1=value1&param2=value2
#EXTINF:10,
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment5_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b&param1=value1&param2=value2
#EXTINF:10,
http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment6_3_av.ts?e=6889c9ad1087852b&param1=value1&param2=value2
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

the playlist works fine, and plays no problem! Obviously it is not ideal to amend the m3u8 with these parameters manually, is there a way to set these parameters for the url calls automatically?

Answer (score 2):

it is too late to answer. But might be helpful to you. I didn't test but problem is in your way of coding. especially in following lines.

```
for(int i= 0;i<paramsSplit.length;i++)
{
     String key = paramsSplit[i].substring(0, playlistUrl.indexOf("="));
     String value = paramsSplit[i].substring(playlistUrl.indexOf("=")+1, playlistUrl.length() );
     headers.put(key, value);//e.g headers.put("param1", "value1");
 }
```

It might be like this

```
for(int i= 0;i<paramsSplit.length;i++)
    {
         String key = paramsSplit[i].substring(0, paramsSplit[i].indexOf("="));
         String value = paramsSplit[i].substring(paramsSplit[i].indexOf("=")+1, paramsSplit[i].length() );
         headers.put(key, value);//e.g headers.put("param1", "value1");
     }
```

Please try and verify with the help of Log.

Answer (score 1):

Everything after "?" mark is NOT headers, but query params.

If you wanna send this query params not only for m3u8 playlist, but for each media segment there is only one way to do so - you have to hardcode this params in playlist (segment urls).

To send them only with playlist request you have to set Url with query params in itself as data source. Like that:
    setDataSource("http://myserver/playlist/336385.smil/segment1_3_av.m3u8?e=6889c9ad1087852b&param1=value1&param2=value2")

- you can try to use overloaded version of API `setDataSource(Uri)`